# multiprocessing python scripts with delay

Tags: python-3.x

I have three independent python scripts which are executing three sensors.
One sensor has a calibration process so it takes few seconds to start logging.

I want to add a delay ( 5 seconds  delay for b.py and c.py) in start for my other two scripts.
Any idea how to make it.

```
import os                                                                       
from multiprocessing import Pool                                                


processes = ('a.py', 'b.py', 'c.py')                                    


def run_process(process):                                                             
    os.system('python3 {}'.format(process))                                       


pool = Pool(processes=3)                                                        
pool.map(run_process, processes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `os.system`, you can use the in-built `sleep` command to to add a delay

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool


processes = (('a.py', 0), ('b.py', 5), ('c.py', 5))


def run_process(process):
    os.system(f'sleep {process[1]} && python3 {process[0]}')


pool = Pool(processes=3)
pool.map(run_process, processes)
```

Comment: is it for python3 ?
im getting a syntaxerror on the line 
os.system...............

Comment: Yes. Formatting strings are in Python 3